# Binding a Laravel service provider on specific routes

Tags: laravel, service-provider

Is there a way to register a service provider in Laravel just for certain routes/URLs? I would like to know if it's possible to bind a service only where you need it and if it helps reduce the strain while booting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure that it's possible to register a service provider only on particular routes, however you could defer it. Just set

```
protected $defer = true;
```

on your service provider then this will only be resolved when needed which should improve performance depending on your particular use case.

For more [check out the official docs on this](https://laravel.com/docs/master/providers#deferred-providers) here but it might just be what you need.

Comment: I missed this spot in the docs. This will do just fine. Thank you @Mike.

Comment: Just to note, if ever needed, it is *possible* to conditionally add a service provider with the `register()` method on the application instance ([docs](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Contracts/Foundation/Application.html#method_register))... but the answer is correct - if it's just a performance concern, Laravel already solves this with the `$defer` property.